# what substitution do i use to solve this triple integral?

Tags: definite-integrals

I have a density function $p(x, y)=(x^4 +y^4)(x^2 +y^2)$
and i need to calculate mass of tile that lies in first quadrant
between   $1<  xy<3$ and  $1< x^2 - y^2<3$ .

I think a change of variable to polar would help me, but cant figure how to make 
domain easier and function easier to manage.
thanks for help

Comment: After a lot of algebra (using Maple), and a little Calculus, I get an answer of exactly $26$, but I'm not too confident in that result.

Comment: By the way, in this context, it's a double integral, not a triple integral, right?

Answer (score 0):

---

Define the subset $D\subseteq\mathbb{R}_{>0}^{2}$ of the first quadrant by the inequalities,

$$D:=\{\left(x,y\right)\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}^{2}\mid1\le xy\le 3\land1\le x^{2}-y^{2}\le3\}.$$

Given a density function $\sigma:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{\ge0}$ defined via the polynomial

$$\sigma{\left(x,y\right)}:=\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)\left(x^{4}+y^{4}\right),$$

the total mass of the region $D$ will be equal to the double integral

$$\operatorname{m}{\left(D\right)}=\iint_{D}\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\sigma{\left(x,y\right)}.$$

As you discovered for yourself, changing to polar coordinates doesn't seem to make the region of integration any less complicated. If we want the new integration region to be as simple as possible after changing variables, then you need a substitution that maps the region $D$ to a rectangle $R=\left[a,b\right]\times\left[c,d\right]\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{2}$, for some $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}\land a<b\land c<d$.

---

Consider the following change of variables:

$$\begin{cases}
&xy=u\\
&\frac{x^{2}-y^{2}}{2}=v.\\
\end{cases}$$

For each ordered pair $\left(u,v\right)\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}^{2}$, there is a (unique) ordered pair $\left(x,y\right)\in\{\left(a,b\right)\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}^{2}\mid0<b<a\}$ satisfying the change-of-variable relations above, i.e., the transformation is a bijection from $\{\left(a,b\right)\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}^{2}\mid0<b<a\}$ to $\mathbb{R}_{>0}^{2}$ with inverse substitution

$$\begin{cases}
&x=\sqrt{v+\sqrt{u^{2}+v^{2}}}\\
&y=\frac{u}{\sqrt{v+\sqrt{u^{2}+v^{2}}}}.\\
\end{cases}$$

The determinant of the Jacobian matrix is found to be (after some perhaps tedious calculations),

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial\left(x,y\right)}{\partial\left(u,v\right)}
&=\det\pmatrix{\frac{u}{2\sqrt{u^{2}+v^{2}}\sqrt{v+\sqrt{u^{2}+v^{2}}}}
&\frac{\sqrt{v+\sqrt{u^{2}+v^{2}}}}{2\sqrt{u^{2}+v^{2}}}\\\
\frac{\sqrt{v+\sqrt{u^{2}+v^{2}}}}{2\sqrt{u^{2}+v^{2}}}
&-\frac{u}{2\sqrt{u^{2}+v^{2}}\sqrt{v+\sqrt{u^{2}+v^{2}}}}}\\
&=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u^{2}+v^{2}}}.\\
\end{align}$$

Finally, our change of variables yields the following result:

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{m}{\left(D\right)}
&=\iint_{D}\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\sigma{\left(x,y\right)}\\
&=\iint_{R}\mathrm{d}u\,\mathrm{d}v\,\left|\frac{\partial\left(x,y\right)}{\partial\left(u,v\right)}\right|\sigma{\left(x\left(u,v\right),y\left(u,v\right)\right)}\\
&=\iint_{\left[1,3\right]\times\left[\frac12,\frac32\right]}\mathrm{d}u\,\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{2\left(u^{2}+2v^{2}\right)\cdot2\sqrt{u^{2}+v^{2}}}{2\sqrt{u^{2}+v^{2}}}\\
&=2\int_{1}^{3}\mathrm{d}u\int_{\frac12}^{\frac32}\mathrm{d}v\,\left(u^{2}+2v^{2}\right)\\
&=26.\blacksquare\\
\end{align}$$

The simplicity of the last integral is our payoff for all the tedious intermediate algebraic steps (many of which I've omitted here for the sake of space).

---

**Ending Note:** The coordinate transformation used in the solution above actually does have a name. In addition to Cartesian and polar coordinates, there are also [parabolic coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_coordinates), and if you're  really curious there is an entire zoo of exotic coordinate systems you can read about there as well, but I digress... ;)

---

Comment: that's really smart, noticing that u=xy, y=1/2 (x^2-y^2). i would've given up at the jacobian (looks like a monster). is there a reason you used y=1/2(x^2-y^2), instead of say, y=x^2-y^2

Comment: @SakethMalyala You could use $(x^2-y^2)=v$ if you wanted to. The derivation would then be almost identical to mine above, except you'd need to replace $v$ with $\frac12v$ in all the equations. This adds factors of $\frac14$ and $\sqrt{2}$ in a dozen different places, making an already annoying algebra problem *even more* annoying. In short, it's just more convenient. ;)

Comment: @SakethMalyala Also, the Jacobian may look big and scary, but notice that the matrix has the form $\pmatrix{A &B\\\ B& -A}$, and so its determinant is of the form $-A^2-B^2$. This gets rid of most the square roots right away.

Comment: wow. but obviously, not that way for all Jacobians

Comment: thanks. i followed it through but did inverse of jacobian to make it easier, ie   1 /( d(uv)/(d(xy)) whyich makes things much easier, then the answer cancels with the (x^2 +y^2) in function.